# Priority of symbols in a notation for projections

Tags: computability

We define an initial function called projection as $$I^k_i(n_1,\ldots,n_k) = n_i, \quad i \leq 1 \leq k, \quad k \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Suppose now that we want to define it in some programming language where we have no access to superscripting nor subscripting. Should we call it `Iki` or `Iik`?

My stand point is that it should be `Iki` so that we first describe the nature of function, that it comes from a set of functions that take `k` arguments. But, the other approach is also understandable because it emphasizes the purpose of function, that it returns the `i`-th coordinate.
It may also be that priorities don't go from left to right as I imagine it.

Is there any convention on priority of symbols in this type of notation?

Comment: It’s completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no convention.

In some languages, there is an idiomatic name for the function that extracts the first element of the tuple (e.g., `fst`, `hd`) and/or the function that extracts the second element (e.g., `snd`).